# View.Frame equivalent in the Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I have been working on `iOS` for a while and implemented the following code where it shows `WebView` in the View.

```
UIView contentView = new UIView();
UIWebView webView = new UIWebView(contentView.Frame);
```

I wonder how the above code could be written in the `Android`. I have written the following but getting error. I am newbie to the Android.

```
View contentView = new View();
WebView webView = new WebView(contentView.LayoutParamaters);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a misunderstanding of the differences between iOS and Android and how Xamarin supports cross platform C#. The APIs between the 2 platforms are very different, while `UIView` is conceptually similar to `View` in reality they map to different APIs. [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/) is an iOS specific api and [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) is an Android specific API, they are each a thin layer on top of the corresponding native controls and have nothing to do with each other.

I'd suggest working through some of the Xamarin.Android tutorials to get an idea of the differences between Android and iOS.

**Regarding the errors:**

The constructor for `View` needs a [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) provided through to the constructor. You can do this in 2 ways, provide the owning activity or the global application context:

```
// In the scope of an Activity.
View contentView = new View(this); // "this" is the activity reference.

// In another scope...
View contentView = new View(Android.App.Application.Context);
```

For your 2nd error, `WebView` does not have a constructor that takes that parameter.

Fix it by providing nothing:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example of how to show a WebView. The layout XML for your Activity would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/yourWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout
```

And the code of your Activity would just be this...

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourWebView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Or if you wanted to add the WebView programmatically, your Activity code would look something like this...

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerView);
        webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        parent.addView(webView, 0);
    }
}
```